# Tumblr image remove the limit

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr

I want to get all of the image from my Tumblr blog, (no limit)

even if I change the limit to the large number, by default it became 20 images, I just want to know what is wrong on my codes that I created, please help.. thanks in advance

please check the fiddle above to check the result.

here's [my code on jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/jazzu20/jrLkmd6w/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var tumblrUrl = 'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/';
  var blogUrl = 'blog.campbrandgoods.com';
  var apiType = '/posts';
  var apiKey = 'VtZPFbyp0dLYfOespTdo6oJyOE0nZx4anBSa46j9OoJO4SBIjg';
  var limit = 995;
  
  var postUrl = tumblrUrl + blogUrl + apiType + '?api_key=' + apiKey + '&limit=' + limit;
  
  var tileContainer = $('ul#tiles');
 
  $.ajax({
    url: postUrl,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    complete: function(){
      
    },
    success: function( strData ){
      
      console.log(strData.response.posts);
      
      var posts = strData.response.posts;
      $.each(posts, function (i, v) {
        if(typeof v.photos !== 'undefined') {
          var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
          var info = $($.parseHTML(v.caption)).text();
          tileContainer.append('<li class="item"><div class="tile-img-container"><img src="' + v.photos[0].alt_sizes[2].url + '"></div><div class="tile-info-container"><a class="various fancybox" href="' + v.post_url + '">' + info + '</a></div></li>');
          //tileContainer.append('<li class="item"><div class="tile-img-container"><img src="' + v.photos[0].alt_sizes[2].url + '"></div><div class="tile-info-container"><a title="' + info + '" class="various fancybox" href="' + v.photos[0].original_size.url + '">' + info + '</a></div></li>');
        }
      });
           
      tileContainer.gridalicious({selector: '.item', gutter: 5, animate: true});
      
      $('ul#tiles').on('click', 'li.item', function (e) {
       var href = $(this).find('.tile-info-container').find('a').attr('href');
        $(this).parents('.item').find('.tile-info-container').find('a').trigger('click');
        window.open(href);
        //$(this).find('.tile-info-container').find('a').trigger('click');
   
      });
      
      $('ul#tiles').on('click', 'li.item a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      });
      /*
      
      $("a.fancybox").fancybox({
        'type': 'image',
  'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
  'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
  'speedIn'  : 600, 
  'speedOut'  : 200, 
  'overlayShow' : true,
        'autoScale'     :   false,         
     'autoSize'      :   false,
         overlayOpacity: 0.7,
         overlayColor: '#000',
         onStart  :function () {
        
          $('#fancybox-inner').css('width', '97%');
           $('#fancybox-inner').css('height', '97%');
          
        },
        onComplete: function(){
   $('#fancybox-inner').css('width', '97%');
          $('#fancybox-inner').css('height', '97%');
  }
   });
      */
      
      $('.tile-img-container').on('click', function (e) {
       $(this).parents('.item').find('.tile-info-container').find('a').trigger('click');
       e.preventDefault();
      });
      
      
    }
  });
  
  
});
```

```css
#tiles li.item .tile-info-container {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">

<div id="page" class="row">
  
  <div class="col-md-12 details">
 <ul id="tiles">
    </ul>
  </div>
  
</div>
  
</div>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: The `limit` is `20`. Use `offset` to get posts `21-40`: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts

Comment: tnx for the reply.. is it possible to get all of my post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the [Tumblr api docs](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2), it is clearly stated that for the request `/posts`, you're only allowed to have a limit that goes from 1 to 20.

The approach I'd take would be a recursive function that takes an `offset` argument. (from the following I've removed some code that wasn't working / was commented out)

```
function GetImages(offset) {
    var postUrl = tumblrUrl + blogUrl + apiType + '?api_key=' + apiKey + '&limit=20&offset=' + offset;
    $.ajax({
        url: postUrl,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        complete: function(){

        },
        success: function( strData ){

            console.log(strData.response.posts);

            var posts = strData.response.posts;
            $.each(posts, function (i, v) {
                if(typeof v.photos !== 'undefined') {
                    var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
                    var info = $($.parseHTML(v.caption)).text();
                    tileContainer.append('<li class="item"><div class="tile-img-container"><img src="' + v.photos[0].alt_sizes[2].url + '"></div><div class="tile-info-container"><a class="various fancybox" href="' + v.post_url + '">' + info + '</a></div></li>');
                    //tileContainer.append('<li class="item"><div class="tile-img-container"><img src="' + v.photos[0].alt_sizes[2].url + '"></div><div class="tile-info-container"><a title="' + info + '" class="various fancybox" href="' + v.photos[0].original_size.url + '">' + info + '</a></div></li>');
                }
            });


            $('ul#tiles').on('click', 'li.item', function (e) {
                var href = $(this).find('.tile-info-container').find('a').attr('href');
                $(this).parents('.item').find('.tile-info-container').find('a').trigger('click');
                window.open(href);
                //$(this).find('.tile-info-container').find('a').trigger('click');

            });


            $('ul#tiles').on('click', 'li.item a', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            $('.tile-img-container').on('click', function (e) {
                $(this).parents('.item').find('.tile-info-container').find('a').trigger('click');
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            // actual changed part
            if (typeof offset === "undefined") {
                offset = 0;
            }
            // (to avoid having to load a hundred pages for each time it was tested, there was also this in the if: `offset < 100 &&`)
            if (((offset + 20) < strData.response.total_posts)) {
                GetImages(offset + 20);
            }
        }
    });
}
GetImages(0);
```

Comment: tnx for this Howl, but i tried to copy and paste to fiddle, its not working

Comment: If you have just copy pasted the code and changed it with the one on the fiddle (as in you deleted all the original fiddle's code), of course it won't work. on the original fiddle, delete everything from line 11 to line 78, add the code I posted in its place.

Comment: btw. is it possible that it will load only when you scroll down?

Comment: Sure, it's called infinite scrolling, and quite popular nowadays. Just google it and plenty of libraries will appear, like [this one](https://github.com/pklauzinski/jscroll). For using it with the mentioned code, you would put the `offset` variable in the global scope rather than having it as a function argument, delete the recursiveness, and trigger the GetImages function when the infinite scroll event is triggered.

Comment: You can actually fetch 50 posts as the maximum, 20 is the default.